# How is a CSS percentage unit converted to pixels by browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I am working on a UI that needs to be able to convert between percentage and pixel units but I miss a credible resource to give me an exact overview of how this is done. It appears to be anything but trivial as it is context-dependent, yet [specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#percentages) appear very vague:

> “Percentage values are always relative to another quantity, for example a length. Each property that allows percentages also defines the quantity to which the percentage refers. This quantity can be a value of another property for the same element, the value of a property for an ancestor element, a measurement of the formatting context (e.g., the width of a containing block), or something else.”

Maybe it is the wrong resource? Anyway, I figure there must be a common way that browsers solve this, I just have not been able to find it – and MDN has not provided much insight.

I thought I'd found a pretty good resource [here](https://jameshfisher.com/2019/12/29/what-are-css-percentages/) and so, I went on to implement conversions for the CSS property, top, for the ul element with class: submenu, which is absolutely positioned:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>
        <ul class="submenu">
           <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul
```

According to the resource, the top and bottom properties refer to the height of the containing block. So I figured, I could pull it from the parentNode of the ul, which would be a li element. However, something was off and when I went through the numbers it became apparent that the reference element was not the parent li, even though it is a block element, but instead the parent ul (id="navigation").

I am not saying that this does not make sense from a styling perspective but sadly, I can conclude that the resource, I had found, is not always correct. I would just LOVE to have an exact specification, so I will know for each CSS property that can take a percentage unit:

- What is the reference element?
- What is the reference property?

If someone could point me to something like that it would be a great help.

EDIT: I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdwoazt1/6/) to illustrate my problem. Variable names are quite long, but hopefully meaningful.

Comment: There is no specific rule. It really depend on your html AND CSS. There is a ton of rules around percetange and you will get afraid If I list all them to you (I I find the time to do it). If you want it for a specific case give us the full code

Comment: as I told you, we need the CSS of your code to give an accurate expalanation. the containing block cannot be defined by only the HTML

Comment: I was afraid of that. However, a ton is ok as long as the info is correct. As I have illustrated in my question, MDN's info on the [top property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) is incorrect for nested uls because the reference element is not the containing block (a li-element), but instead the containing ul.

Comment: What do you need the CSS for? You have the HTML that describes my particular situation and I have already stated that the li is a block element. I would not write that if I had styled it to be something else. What do you mean by: "the containing block cannot be defined by only the HTML"? I get that you can use CSS to change a block element to be inline.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details <-- the containing block depend on a lot of things (more that what you think) so the HTML you gave and you described are useless, no one can answer you question. We need the CSS with it to give you an answer

Comment: Ok. I have attached a jsfiddle to illustrate my issue, which is basically that I thought the li was the containing block. But I can see now from the link you provided that it is the nearest ancestor that has a position of relative or absolute - hence the ul. Thanks

Comment: because the containing block of position:absolute element is the nearest positioned ancestor and in this case it's not the parent but the ancestor ul ... you see why we need your CSS

Comment: I get it. But I would also say that I had already written about the containing block and it was pretty obvious that I had misunderstood what that meant. That's why I was asking for a general resource and not an explanation to the specific problem. Your link gave me the explanation I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: `.submenuContainer { position: relative; }` take a look at [offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent)